# How to select a region of a Highcharts by a Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two different types of charts(Let's take them as "A" chart and "B" chart). They have connections.

What I want to know is if I click on a point in "A" chart , I want to select the relevant slice in "B" pie chart.

**Edit:**
http://i58.tinypic.com/bf2cle.jpg

If I click on FRM5(1) relevant part(2) from graph should slice.

Comment: Add some code please?

Comment: Please look at the image. Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to first chart click event ([docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.click)), and in that click event call for a second chart `setExtremes()` ([docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)).

**==EDIT==**

Since we have full description, this is correct answer:

Use `point.slice()` [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.slice).

Comment: Setting extremes is not what I want to do. Please find image and description added.